# C++ matrix multiplication not producing correct output

Tags: c++, matrix

I am trying to multiply two 2D arrays in C++ , but the expected output is not correct , following is my logic what i am trying -

```
 int A[l][m]; //creates A l*m matrix or a 2d array.      
for(int i=0; i<l; i++)    //This loops on the rows.
{
    for(int j=0; j<m; j++) //This loops on the columns
    {
        A[i][j] = i+j; // Allocating values to A matrix
    }
}

int B[m][n]; //creates B m*n matrix or a 2d array.
for(int i=0; i<m; i++)    //This loops on the rows.
{
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++) //This loops on the columns
    {
        B[i][j] = i+j+1; // Allocating values to B matrix
    }
}

int C[l][n]; //creates C m*n matrix or a 2d array.
for(int i=0; i<l; i++)    //This loops on the rows.
{
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++) //This loops on the columns
    {
        for(int k=0; k<m; k++) //This loops on the columns
        {
            C[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j]; // Allocating values to C matrix
            //product[row][col] += aMatrix[row][inner] * bMatrix[inner][col];
        }
    cout << C[i][j] << "  ";
          }
       cout << "\n";
}
```

if I give l=2 , m=2 and n =2 I am getting following output -

-1077414723  3
15  8

Which is incorrect , can anybody advice me what is wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to initialize `C[i][j]` to 0.

Or you could start the sum at `0` and then assign to `C[i][j]` after:

```
//...
for(int j=0; j<n; j++) //This loops on the columns
{
   int sum = 0;
   for(int k=0; k<m; k++) //This loops on the columns
   {
      sum += A[i][k] * B[k][j]; // Allocating values to C matrix
      //product[row][col] += aMatrix[row][inner] * bMatrix[inner][col];
   }
   C[i][j] = sum;
   cout << C[i][j] << "  ";
}
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

You have *undefined behaviour*: `int C[l][n];` is declared but never initialised.

Quite often, `memset` is used to zero the memory, or just loop through the elements and set them to zero (which with modern compilers, is just as fast).

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialized c[i][j] to 0.
Use

```
int c[2][2]= {{0}};
```

This will initialize just the first element of the array. However, if you initialize some of the elements of an array, the ones which are not initialized would be set to 0.